# Reducibility of representation of SU(2)

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am working with a SU(2) invariant system which has symmetry generators of the form
$$
\lambda_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\;;\qquad \lambda_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -i & 0\\
0 & i & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\;;\qquad \lambda_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It can be checked easily that the generators satisfy the su(2) algebra $[\lambda_i,\lambda_j] = 2i \epsilon_{ijk}\lambda_k$, where the $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the completely antisymmetric Levi-Civita tensor.

If we now define unitary matrices of the form $U = e^{i\sum_i \alpha_i \lambda_i}$, the matrices will be elements of the SU(2) group. I have now the following questions:

1. Is this an irreducible representation of the SU(2) group with dimension 4, or is this reducible?
2. If it is a reducible representation, what will be the decomposition of the representation in terms of irreducible representations? I am asking this because I want to find the characters for this representation.

P.S. I have a physics background. So, I only have a basic understanding of group theory and group representations.

Edit 1: I see now that the representation is reducible with help from the comments. The space spanned by the vectors (1,0,0,0) and (0,0,0,1) form an invariant subspace, thus implying that it is a reducible representation. Any help with the second question is still appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to find nonzero vectors annihilated by all three generators?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see that the vectors (1,0,0,0) and (0,0,0,1) are annihilated by all the generators as they have eigenvalues 0. Can you please explain how is this related to reducibility?

Comment: Now check that these vectors will be fixed by the image of $SU(2)$ under your representation.

Comment: I am not entirely familiar with the terminology, but I guess it means that the vectors remain unchanged when multiplied by any SU(2) matrix under the representation above, and I agree with that. What does that tell us? I am sorry, if it is a dumb question, I am quite new to this.

Comment: I think I see what the problem is. What is the definition of an irreducible representation that you have learned in your class or by reading?

Comment: Okay, from the definition, it means that the space spanned by the two invariant basis vectors forms an invariant subspace. So it is a reducible representation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149428/discussion-between-physics-quantum975-and-moishe-kohan).

Comment: For the second question, the representation you have splits as the direct sum $V_0\oplus V_0\oplus V_1$, where $V_0$ is the trivial 1-dimensional representation and $V_1$ is the fundamental representation of $SU(2)$ (of the weight $1$, i.e. the unique 2-dimensional representation). The proof is pretty much what was discussed in the chat.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks! I figured that out. Will add an answer shortly. Final question, does the group integration/volume element depend on the dimensionality of the representation?

Comment: The last question I do not understand. You may want to ask a new question.